# How to access to the coordinates of the icons in the action bar?

Tags: android, menuitem

In the tutorial of my application, I'd like to be able to *point* to particular icons in the action bar, like e.g. with the yellow arrow pointing at the bulb in the picture below:

[image]

Here is the XML code for the menu items shown in the picture:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/AbErase"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:title="@string/Erase"
    android:tooltipText="@string/Erase"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    />

<item android:id="@+id/AbImmediateImplementation"
    android:title="@string/ImmediateImplementation"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:orderInCategory="20"
    app:showAsAction="never|withText"
    android:enabled="true" />

<item android:id="@+id/AbSuggest"
    android:title="@string/Suggest"
    android:tooltipText="@string/Suggest"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_lightbulb_outline_white_48dp"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

<item android:id="@+id/AbUndo"
    android:title="@string/ActionBarUndo"
    android:tooltipText="@string/ActionBarUndo"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
    android:orderInCategory="51"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

<item android:id="@+id/AbStep"
    android:title="@string/ActionBarStep"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

.....
</menu>
```

Here is the code I used to get the `View` associated to the *AbErase* menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; mContext adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    actionBar.collapseActionView();

    eraseItem = menu.findItem(id.AbErase);
    View eraseItemView = eraseItem.getActionView();
    int eraseItemViewLeft = eraseItemView.getLeft();

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

When this code executes, *eraseItemView* is *null*.
How can I get the *Left* coordinate of each individual icon in the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, using the debugger, I found that the `ToolBar` shown above has 3 children:

- at index 0: an `ActionMenuView`
- at index 1: a `Linearlayout` that contains the `Spinner`
- at index 2: an `AppCompatImageButton` for the navigation button

The `ActionMenuView` has 5 children of type `ActionMenuItemView`. These are the icons I was looking for.

So to point to the bottom-left corner of the second icon, I use this code:

```
    ViewGroup overflowMenu = (ViewGroup) scToolbar.getChildAt(0);
    int bulbLeft = overflowMenu.getLeft() + overflowMenu.getChildAt(1).getLeft();
```